# NUnit - Can't retrieve a category property

Tags: c#, automation, nunit

Please bare in mind I'm a novice programmer and very new to C#

I am attempting to utilise the "Category" property in a test but whenever I try to retrieve it in any way I'm not having any luck. It either fails or returns as blank. I think I'm not reading it properly but I can't find any information for it.

My test looks like this:

```
[TestCase(TestName = "Testing Purposes Only")]
[Category("TESTING")]
public void testingPurposesOnly()
{
    //Some testing code
}
```

For now, all I want to do is to be able to refer to the current test's category value. I'm doing so like this:

```
LogMsg(TestContext.CurrentTest.Test.Property["Category"]);
```

I've as far as realizing that this will return a 'list' of categories? Like I said I'm a novice!

All I want to be able to do is access the category I have set in the test header so I can pass it onto something else as a string. What is the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CategoryAttributes on a test create the Category properties. Either of them will give you a list of categories on the test.

However, reading between the lines, I'm guessing you want the category **which caused the test to be run**. Sorry, but you cannot get that.

1. The test may not have been selected to run because of a category. Perhaps it was selected by name or was just run as a part of running all tests.
2. The test may have been selected by a logical combination of categories and perhaps other things like the name, a property, etc.
3. All of this is the business of the runner. To put it bluntly, your test has no business dealing with it. The NUnit framework knows what categories or other filters were specified when running the test and includes those in the XML report. It does not give you info like "This particular test was selected because..."
4. My guess is that you are trying to create some kind of log or report. The intent of the NUnit architecture is that you would put that code into a separate program that reads the result file or into an engine extension. The test itself doesn't even know what runner executed it, much less why.

Since you are a novice, I suggest you use plain vanilla NUnit for a while, before trying to extend it. :-)

Comment: Hi Charlie, thanks very much for your feedback. You are exactly right of course, I'm trying to take the Category of a test so I can send it to an external reporting tool (Extent Reports) in order for that tool to categorize the results. I can set a seperate variable in all of my tests to do this I was just hoping to use the Category so all the previously written tests would retro fit automatically. Thanks for the info though, saves me wasting a lot of time!

Answer (score 1):

In place of

```
[TestCase(TestName = "Testing Purposes Only")]
[Category("TESTING")]
public void testingPurposesOnly()
{
    //Some testing code
}
```

Use category like :

```
[TestCase(TestName = "Testing Purposes Only", Category = "TESTING")]
public void testingPurposesOnly()
{
    //Some testing code
}
```

after this you can access category with same code as:

```
var categories = TestContext.CurrentContext.Test?.Properties["Category"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can go straight way and extract property using reflection:

```
public class TestClass
{
  [Category("TESTING")]
  public void TestMethod()
  {
    var method = typeof(TestClass).GetRuntimeMethod(nameof(TestClass.TestMethod)), new Type[]{});
    var attribute = method.GetCustomAttribute<Category>();
  }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think I'm going to have to do some more reading to fully understand it however. It seems like a complex way to extract something which seems so simple though?

For example, for the Test Name its as easy as:

var name = TestContext.CurrentTest.Test.Name;

I was hoping extracting the category would be something equally as simple? Like I said, novice

Comment: Well seems as far as I understand there is no way to get exact category of  running test. You can only retrieve the collection of available categories. So this is just sample reflection to get  the attribute from  a method. Maybe not the right solution but it may work.

Answer (score 0):

`var categories = TestContext.CurrentContext.Test?.Properties["Category"];`

Another way to get the Category Value in the Test Methods is :

```
 var myAttribute = this.GetType().GetMethod("AddYourMethodName").GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<CategoryAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
        Console.WriteLine(myAttribute.Name);
```